# XmlPullParser getAttributeValue returns null

Tags: android, xml, xml-parsing, xmlpullparser

I have the following XML structure stored in my *assets/xml* folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<homescreen>
    <homeitem name="Name1"
              subtext="Description1"
              icon="iconresource1" />
    <homeitem name="Name2"
              subtext="Description2"
              icon="iconresource2" />
    <homeitem name="Name3"
              subtext="Description3"
              icon="iconresource3" />
</homescreen>
```

I'm reading each individual `homeitem` using an XmlPullParser:

```java
int event;
String TAG_ITEM = "homeitem";
while ((event = parser.next()) != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if (event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        String tag = parser.getName();
        if (TAG_ITEM.equals(tag)) {
            // Works - Logs "Name1"
            Log.d(LOG_NAME, parser.getAttributeValue(0));

            // Works - Logs "name"
            Log.d(LOG_NAME, parser.getAttributeName(0));

            // Works - Logs ""
            Log.d(LOG_NAME, parser.getAttributeNamespace(0));

            // Fails - Logs null
            Log.d(LOG_NAME, parser.getAttributeValue(XmlPullParser.NO_NAMESPACE, "name"));
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is: using `getAttributeValue(String, String)` **always returns null**. Using `getAttributeValue(Integer)` works fine. What am I doing wrong?

Device: Nexus 10, Stock KitKat 4.4

Answer (score 19, accepted):

try this :

```
parser.getAttributeValue(null, "name");
```

Comment: This works. I guess I was just assuming this wanted the same namespace as returned by `getAttributeNamespace`.

Comment: What are supposed to be passing (or not passing, as it seems) to this parameter anyway?

Comment: Works just use this in START_TAG case

Comment: why do we always pass null in the first parameter(namespace) ?

Comment: I think its default value if attribute does not exist.

Comment: @KuldipSharma it's not the default value, it's the namespace. Would usually be left null