# parse xml attributes in android

Tags: java, android

I am parsing this xml. I want to get all the values from attributes but after searching a lot I am only able to fetch the first item value. Can anybody let me know how can I get all the id from all the items. I have pasted my code also

XML:

```
<query>
   <item id='9173' name='A'/>
   <item id='9174' name='B'/>
   <item id='9175' name='C'/>
   <item id='9176' name='D'/>
   <item id='9174' name='E'/>
</query>
```

Code:

```
boolean done = false;
while (!done) {
    int eventType = parser.next();
    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
    }
    else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        Map<String,String> attributes = getAttributes(parser);
        if (parser.getName().equals("query")) {
            done = true;
        }
    }
}
private Map<String,String>  getAttributes(XmlPullParser parser) throws Exception { Map<String,String> attrs=null;
    int acount=parser.getAttributeCount();
    if(acount != -1) {
        Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"Attributes for ["+parser.getName()+"]");
        attrs = new HashMap<String,String>(acount);
        for(int x=0;x<acount;x++) {
            Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"\t["+parser.getAttributeName(x)+"]=" +
                  "["+parser.getAttributeValue(x)+"]");
            attrs.put(parser.getAttributeName(x), parser.getAttributeValue(x));
        }
    }
    else {
        throw new Exception("Required entity attributes missing");
    }
    return attrs;
}
```

Comment: some indentation and formating would help readability !

Comment: thanks. I was having problem in pasting the code. posted first time

Comment: As far as I can see, it should work, how do you know it's not working, you're not doing anything with the attributes you retreive?

Comment: Log.d(MY_DEBUG_TAG,"\t["+parser.getAttributeName(x)+"]=" +
                  "["+parser.getAttributeValue(x)+"]"); ...... It print this log only one time. It should print 6 times

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20216243/xmlpullparser-getattributevalue-returns-null  Finally I find my answer here..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `getAttributes` you call `getAttributeCount` which, [according to the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html) (emphasis mine) :

> Returns the number of attributes of the current start tag, **or -1 if the current event type is not START_TAG**

As your if condition juste before make sure that you are on a END_TAG, this cannot work and your `getAttributes` call should always throw an exception.

You should probably rewrite it like this (disclaimer : not tested) :

```
boolean done = false;
while (!done) {

    if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

        if (parser.getName().equals("query")) {
            done = true;
        } else if  (parser.getName().equals("item")) {
            Map<String,String> attributes = getAttributes(parser);
        }
    }
    else if (eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

    }
    int eventType = parser.next();
}
```